# CodeIgniter detect if Default Controller route was used

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

In CodeIgniter, is there a way to know if a user was sent to the Default Controller because the route sent them there, OR because the user actually entered that controller in the URL bar.

In other words,  ---.com/home and ---.com could both send you to the 'home' controller, because you have set

`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`

But only ---.com/ would invoke CI to fetch the "default_controller"
So, how do I detect this?  If only there was a boolean function that could tell me this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `$this->uri->total_segments()` ... or one of the other functions in the URI class to deduce this ...

```
if($this->uri->total_segments() === 0){
    //user came in by default_controller
}
```

[URI Class Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: Where could this go?  I'd like to stay out of core, yet detect if before the re-route has happened?

Comment: This would have to be in the index function of the default controller. Why detect before it happens? At that point, it sounds like you need to set up different routing rules.

Comment: Hey this works.  I am working with rules where permission and routing are battling for the decision on where users with a specific permission will go.  But for the long term, I may want to try your second suggestion about other routing rules.  Thanks!